# Estimating the parameters of an ellipse

Tags: probability, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition, diagonalization, parameter-estimation

**Problem definition**

Consider a dataset composed by $m$ bivariate measurements
\begin{equation*}
y_j \sim \mathcal{U}(\mathcal{E}(\ell_1,\ell_2,\theta)) \qquad j=1,2,\dots,m
\end{equation*}
uniformly distributed over an ellipse centered in the origin, with semilength $\ell_1$, semiwidth $\ell_2<\ell_1$ and orientation $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$. The orientation angle $\theta$ is the angle between the horizontal axis and the longitudinal axis, where for longidutinal axis I mean the direction of the two major semiaxes that define the semilength of the ellipse.

My objective is to estimate $\theta, \ell_1, \ell_2$ given the dataset $y_{1},\dots,y_m$.

**A starting solution**

The idea is to compute the sample covariance of the dataset
\begin{equation*}\begin{aligned}
S&\triangleq \frac{1}{m-1}\sum_{j=1}^m (y_j-\bar{y})
(y_j-\bar{y})'\\
\bar{y}&\triangleq\frac{1}{m}\sum_{j=1}^m y_j
\end{aligned}\end{equation*}
and then use the eigenvalues-eigenvectors decomposition
\begin{equation*}
S=U\Lambda U' \qquad
U\triangleq\left[\begin{array}{cc}
\cos \hat{\theta} & -\sin\hat{\theta} \\
\sin \hat{\theta} & \cos\hat{\theta} \\
\end{array}\right] \qquad
\Lambda \triangleq \left[\begin{array}{cc}
\lambda_1 & 0 \\
0 & \lambda_2
\end{array}\right]
\end{equation*}
to extrapolate $\ell_1,\ell_2,\theta$ as follows
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\hat{\ell}_1 &\triangleq k \sqrt{\Lambda_{11}} \\
\hat{\ell}_2 &\triangleq k \sqrt{\Lambda_{22}} \\
\hat{\theta} &\triangleq \cos^{-1}(U_{11})
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
where $k$ is a suitable scaling factor that must be determined.

**A more detailed solution**

The previous solution assumes to have an algorithm, treated as a black-box, to diagonalize $S$. Then uses the factors $U, \Lambda$ to define the estimates. Since we are dealing with a $2\times2$ matrix, we can readily solve the diagonalization analytically. This approach provide a better understanding about whats going on in this estimation process.
Let
\begin{equation*}
S=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
S_{11} & S_{12} \\
S_{12} & S_{22}
\end{array}\right]
\end{equation*}
then, we can start to search for the eigenvalues, which are the two solutions $\lambda_{1,2}$ of the quadratic equation
\begin{equation*}
\text{det}\lambda I-S)=0
\qquad
\equiv
\qquad
\lambda^2 - (S_{11}+S_{22})\lambda+S_{11}S_{22}-S_{12}^2=0
\end{equation*}
The eigenvalues are
\begin{equation*}
\lambda_{1,2} = \frac{S_{11}+S_{22}\pm \sqrt{(S_{11}-S_{22})^2+4S_{12}^2}}{2}
\end{equation*}
and, up to a scaling factor $k$,
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\hat{\ell}_1 &= k \sqrt{\lambda_1} \\
\hat{\ell}_2 &= k \sqrt{\lambda_2}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

Now, we can search for the eigenvectors. Setting a generic normalized eigenvector
\begin{equation*}
v\triangleq \left[\begin{array}{c}
\cos \hat{\theta} \\
\sin \hat{\theta}
\end{array}\right]
\end{equation*}
in the system of equations
\begin{equation*}
(\lambda I - S) v= 0
\end{equation*}
gives the equation (for the first component of system, evaluated in $\lambda=\lambda_1$)
\begin{equation*}
(\lambda_1-S_{11})\cos \hat{\theta}-S_{12}\sin \hat{\theta} =0
\end{equation*}
from which follows
\begin{equation*}
\hat{\theta} = \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\lambda_1-S_{11}}{S_{12}}\right)
= \tan^{-1} \left(\frac{S_{22}-S_{11}}{2S_{12}}+\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{S_{11}-S_{22}}{2S_{12}}\right)^2}\right)
\end{equation*}

**Questions**

1. Is there a better approach to estimate the parameter of the underlying ellipse?
2. I'm not sure about the scaling factor. Given that exists, what is its value (or a reasonable appproximation)?